# Firebase realtime database - how to get parent name based on a value of one of its keys

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The structure looks like this:

```
users
    |----username1
         |----uid:value
         username2
         |----uid:value
```

I'm trying to find the best way to get the username value based of the value of it's uid,
This need to be in Java code (Android), So far I found the following code:

```
Query uid = reference.child("users").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
uid.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      String keys=datas.getKey();
      if (keys.equals(uid)) {
        // uid found
      } else {

      }
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: Your code looks good. What is the problem with it?

Comment: Where in the code it takes the parent value which is the username ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and create a model class to fetch value of Uid

```
    DatabaseReference users= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    users.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot post:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                //Use a model class to fetch user id like below
                UIDDetails u=post.getValue(UIDDetails.class);
                String user_id=u.getUid();

                //Here all values will be equal to youy required uid if exists more than one 


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code into your file:

```
    DatabaseReference users= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    final Query userQuery = users.orderByChild("uid");

    userQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

         map.clear();
        if(child.getkey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(uid)){

        //Get the node from the datasnapshot
          String myParentNode = dataSnapshot.getKey();

          for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
          {
             String key = child.getKey().toString();
             String value = child.getValue().toString();
             map.put(key,value);
          }

          }
       }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```